# DFA to regular expression

Tags: regex, dfa

I have already read a couple soultions and tutorials, expecially on Stackoverflow, but can't help myself with a specific issue.
To begin with, I have this DFA:
[image]

And could reduce it to this:

[image]

So that I have the regular expression at (aa|ba|cc)c but missing the returning d. Checking it that far with http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa it looks exactly like my starting DFA but without the d. I tried a lot but am very unsure how to write the d into the RE.

Comment: Where should the `d` even be appearing?  Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: That's actually my question. I don't know how it belongs in the regex. The DFA says it can, but doesn't have to appear at the end. But if it appears, the regex would start all over. Until you end it at q1 and don't return with a d to q0.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It’s pretty clear to me. The string should be the sequence `(aa|ba|cc)c`, should _not end_ with a `d`, but if a `d` appears, it needs the first sequence again in order to be accepted. A regex could be something like `^(?:aa|ba|cc)c(?:d(?:aa|ba|cc)c)*$`.

Comment: @Xufox feel free to post such an answer.

Comment: I doubt if that DFA produces any `ccc` sequence..

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed sequence isn’t quite correct, as pointed out by [revo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39792966/dfa-to-regular-expression#comment66880312_39792966). The correct sequence is `(aa|ba|c)c`.

The regex version (in programming languages) of the whole DFA would be

```
/^(?:aa|ba|c)c(?:d(?:aa|ba|c)c)*$/
```

The formal regex would be

```
(aa|ba|c)c(d(aa|ba|c)c)*
```

`(?:aa|ba|cc)c` is the first sequence that you already figured out (everything from `q0` to `q6`, without the `d` path from `q6` back to `q0`).

Once a `d` appears, you basically need the above sequence *again*. That second instance of the sequence including the `d` can be repeated any number of times, so you use the `*` quantifier.

Comment: Sadly that's not how it would describe a DFA. You can try your regex here: http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa It will give you back an error.

Comment: @KendelVentonda Oh, well, see my edit. I didn’t realize you needed a formal regex instead of a regex as used in programming languages.